# SQLite replace a row in one database from a row in another database

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

I have two database files each with a common single table makeup.  I'd like to replace an entire table row in the first database with the similar row from the second database when a column in the second database has a flag set.  I know how to Attach one database to another but I can't figure out the proper `UPDATE SET` instruction.  I'm looking for string instruction to pass in a kotlin based android studio `android.database.sqlite` execSQL call.

For example:
The table in each database has five columns named - `name,address,date,value,flag`
I open the main database (`main.db`) and call `ATTACH DATABASE` to attach secondary database (`secondary.db`) as 'db2'
I then want to find a row in the main database that matches a row in the secondary database where the name and address fields match and the flag field in the secondary database contains a value of 1.
I then want to replace the main database row with the row from the secondary database

I unsuccessfully tried variations of the following string command for execSQL:

```
val TABLE_NAME = "users"

val COL_NAME = "name"

val COL_ADR = "address"

val COL_DATE = "date"
    
val COL_VAL = "value"
    
val COL_FLG = "flag"

val db = this.writableDatabase

val attachDb = ("ATTACH DATABASE '$secondaryDbFile' AS 'db2'")            
db.execSQL(attachDb) 

val updateRows = ("UPDATE $TABLE_NAME SET ($COL_NAME, $COL_ADR, $COL_DATE, $COL_VAL, $COL_FLG) FROM db2.$TABLE_NAME WHERE $COL_FLG = 1")
db.execSQL(updateRows)
```

I don't have a good enough grasp of SQLite to construct the proper instruction, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax that you use in the `UPDATE` statement is wrong.
You can use [ROW VALUES](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) and update only the columns `date`, `value` and `flag` since the other 2 columns must match.
Also use aliases for the 2 tables (like `t1` and `t2`) to distinguish the columns that have the same names:

```
val db = this.writableDatabase
val attachDb = ("ATTACH DATABASE '$secondaryDbFile' AS db2") // no need for single quotes around db2
db.execSQL(attachDb)
val updateRows = "UPDATE $TABLE_NAME AS t1 " + 
                 "SET ($COL_DATE, $COL_VAL, $COL_FLG) = " +
                 "(SELECT t2.$COL_DATE, t2.$COL_VAL, 1 FROM db2.$TABLE_NAME AS t2 WHERE (t2.$COL_NAME, t2.$COL_ADR) = (t1.$COL_NAME, t1.$COL_ADR) AND t2.$COL_FLG = 1) " +
                 "WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM db2.$TABLE_NAME AS t2 WHERE (t2.$COL_NAME, t2.$COL_ADR) = (t1.$COL_NAME, t1.$COL_ADR) AND t2.$COL_FLG = 1);"
db.execSQL(updateRows)
```

For versions of SQLite that do not allow an alias for the updated table, use this statement:

```
val updateRows = "UPDATE $TABLE_NAME " + 
                 "SET ($COL_DATE, $COL_VAL, $COL_FLG) = " +
                 "(SELECT t2.$COL_DATE, t2.$COL_VAL, 1 FROM db2.$TABLE_NAME AS t2 WHERE (t2.$COL_NAME, t2.$COL_ADR) = ($TABLE_NAME.$COL_NAME, $TABLE_NAME.$COL_ADR) AND t2.$COL_FLG = 1) " +
                 "WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM db2.$TABLE_NAME AS t2 WHERE (t2.$COL_NAME, t2.$COL_ADR) = ($TABLE_NAME.$COL_NAME, $TABLE_NAME.$COL_ADR) AND t2.$COL_FLG = 1);"
```

The syntax of the `UPDATE` statement could be simplified if the version of SQLite was 3.33.0+, but it would not work in Android which up till now, in API Level 31 supports version 3.32.2.

This is the simplified version of the `UPDATE` statement (for future readers):

```
val updateRows = "UPDATE $TABLE_NAME AS t1 " + 
                 "SET ($COL_DATE, $COL_VAL, $COL_FLG) = (t2.$COL_DATE, t2.$COL_VAL, 1) " +
                 "FROM db2.$TABLE_NAME AS t2 WHERE (t2.$COL_NAME, t2.$COL_ADR) = (t1.$COL_NAME, t1.$COL_ADR) AND t2.$COL_FLG = 1;"
```

Comment: Much appreciated forpas, does exactly what I needed!

Comment: Although the statement works on devices running API 30 (sqlite V3.28) , it doesn't work on API 29 (sqlite V3.22).  On Api 29 I get the following error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AS": syntax error.  Is there any way around this bug using alias'?

Comment: @TFont I added another version of the query without the alias of the updated table.

Comment: Thanks again forpas, the query without the alias worked fine in both APIs.